# Asammdf extracting more metadata

Tags: asammdf

Hi I am using asammdf library for handling MF4 files. When I open the file using asammdf GUI , in Info tab I can see information [image: picture here]. I am trying to extract the same info by calling .info() function on the same file as below.

```
data = MDF(r"C:\Users\vaasu\Desktop\data\Recorder_2020-06-05_10-22_0120.MF4")  

print(data.info())
```

But this is only giving channel group information. But I need "program identification" and "Measurement comment" as well. How can I read that using asammdf API?

Answer (score 2):

You can see what attributes are accessed starting with this line https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/blob/af1b9b1a213fbfc33a77d41c9d7aca2257e0c320/asammdf/gui/widgets/file.py#L376

Comment: Thank you. That helped. And is it possible to load metadata of a file without creating an object of MDF? Because `MDF(<filepath>)`  takes more time.

Comment: Do you need the channel group information or just the measurement header information?

Comment: List of channel group and signal names in them. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the info function in the development branch. For a complete overview of the channels you could have a look at the mdf.channels_db dict